# Getting the array mapped to a key in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

How do I get the array mapped to a specific key in a javascript object?

```
assignment = {};
assignment.tab = 'assign';
assignment.yrq = 'B343';
assignment.items = [1234,4567];
```

Displaying the items works:

```
alert(assignment.items); //displays 1234, 4567
```

But when I try to iterate through the items, I get the index numbers:

```
for (item in assignment.items) {
    alert(item); //displays 0, then 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong `for` loop for an array, you should be using a regular `for` loop, not `for-in`, which is commonly used for objects, not arrays

```
for (var i=0; i<assignment.items.length; i++) {
    alert( assignment.items[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your loop to use it as the index

```
for (itemIndex in assignment.items) {
    alert(assignment.items[itemIndex]);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't iterate an _Array_ with `for..in` because non-indices may also be iterated over.

Comment: Good call. Just in case something gets added to the Array prototype, you shouldn't use `for..in` with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just use for loop

```
assignment = {};
assignment.tab = 'assign';
assignment.yrq = 'B343';
assignment.items = [1234,4567];

for(var i = 0; i < assignment.items.length; i++){
    alert(assignment.items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (item in assignment.items) {
    alert(assignment.items[item]); //displays 1234, then 4567
}
```